# IWizardPage turn off Next page and turn on Finish

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

So I am using the org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage class. On the first page, if the user clicks check box A, I want the "Next" button of the wizard to be disabled. And I want the "Finish" button to be enabled. Is this possible? If you setPageComplete(false), then it will disable the "Finish" button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `WizardPage` method:

```
public boolean canFlipToNextPage()
```

to implement your logic for enabling the next page button.

You may need to call

```
getContainer().updateButtons();
```

to get the method called.